# Theme not applying on category page

Tags: magento2

I have installed a theme on Magento 2.3.3 and it is working fine with all categories and product pages except one category which is showing the Luma theme while the products of that category loading installed theme.
I have compared the setting of the category with other categories and found no difference but still not loading the theme.
I have cleaned and flushed cache also deployed static content.

Comment: Have u checked the setting at Scope level?

Comment: no, how to check using scope level